# Unresponsive SonarQube in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, sonarqube, kubernetes, sonarqube-ops

We're creating  a kubernetes deployment for sonar. When using the embedded H2 DB the deployment works fine and SonarQube is available thru the kube Ingress controller.

But when setting JDBC parameters for persistence the SonarQube instance fails to respond to any request and outputs the following error (in logs)

```
01:31:51.000 (unknown):0 warning: already initialized constant Input
01:31:51.000 WARNING: while creating new bindings for class org.jruby.rack.RackInput, 
01:31:51.000 found an existing binding; you may want to run a clean build.
```

Here's the Kubernetes deployment descriptor:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonar-deployment
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonar
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sonar
        image: sonarqube:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        env:
        - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME
          value: sonar
        - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD
          value: sonar
        - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL
          value: "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Deployments is experiment feature for the kubernetes. Use replicationcontroller here is my configuration. It's work in production.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sonarqube
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: services
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: sonarqube
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL
          value: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
        - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME
          value: sonar
        - name: SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD
          value: sonar
        image: sonarqube
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 20
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 9000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 60
        name: sonarqube
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9292
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 1000Mi
```